# 'fseek() + output' Behaves Strange on C Standard I/O Library Memory Streams

Tags: c, memorystream, stdio, fseek

I'm reading the `APUE` and trying out the memory stream in stdio.h. However, I feel very confused on the mechanism of auto-writing `\0` .

Here is what `APUE` said on `5.14 Memory Streams`:

> A null byte is written at the current position in the stream whenever we increase the amount of data in the stream’s buffer and call fclose, fflush, fseek, fseeko, or fsetpos

I did some experiment using the following code, to test what means `Increase the amount of data in the stream's buffer`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BSZ 48

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[BSZ];

    memset(buf, 'a', BSZ-2);
    buf[BSZ-2] = '\0';
    buf[BSZ-1] = 'X';
    printf("Initial buffer content: %s\n", buf);

    if ((fp = fmemopen(buf, BSZ, "w+")) == NULL){
        fputs("fmemopen failed\n", stderr);
        exit(-1);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "hello, world");

    /* Confused Point Here !!! */
    fflush(fp);                   //works as expected
    //fseek(fp, 12, SEEK_SET);    //strange behavior

    printf("after fflush/fseek: %s\n", buf);

    fprintf(fp, "hello, world2");
    fclose(fp);
    printf("after fclose: %s\n", buf);

    exit(0);
}
```

Both `flush()` and `fseek()` will auto-write a `'\0'` after the first output of `"hello, world"`.
The behaviors are different after the second output of 'hello, world' and call fclose():

When I use the `flush()`, the second output of `"hello, world"` is followed by a `'\0'`, which is what I expected:

> Initial buffer content: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>   after fflush/fseek: hello, world
>   after fclose: hello, worldhello, world2

However, when I switch to `fseek(fp, 12, SEEK_SET)`, the second output of `"hello, world"` is not followed by a '\0' any more:

> Initial buffer content: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>   after fflush/fseek: hello, world
>   after fclose: hello, worldhello, world2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

This means the memory stream doesn't treat the second output as `increasing the amount of data`.

I did this experiment on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64) SP1

Do you have any ideas about that?  Or it is actually a bug of the system?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: i can't reproduce your output in my computer(fedora31 Linux), it's the same

Answer (score 0):

[Too long for a comment:]

> A null byte is written at the current position in the stream whenever we increase the amount of data in the stream’s buffer and call fclose, fflush, fseek, fseeko, or fsetpos

Documentation differs regarding the above quote from *APUE*:

The [Linux man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) says:

> When a stream that has been opened for writing is flushed (fflush(3))
>          or closed (fclose(3)), a null byte is written at the end of the
>          buffer if there is space. [...] The stream's file position can be changed with fseek(3) or fseeko(3). Moving the file position past the end of the data already written fills the intervening space with zeros.

[POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html):

> When a stream open for writing is flushed or closed, a null byte shall be written at the current position or at the end of the buffer, depending on the size of the contents.

So POSIX ins't as explitic as the Linux doc at all reagrding what to do on `fseek*`s.